# .htaccess Domain redirect conflicts with addon-domain

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I have a wordpress blog "old.com" hosted in shared hosting where "old.com" is the main domain...
Then decide to redirect this  "old.com" to "new.com" (an addon domain hosted in same hosting)...

I use this code on .htaccess

> Options +FollowSymLinks RewriteEngine on RewriteRule ^(.*)$
>   http://new.com/$1 [R=301,L]

Everything works just fine. I also have an addon domain, "addon1.com" and I still can access this perfectly (I added this "addon1.com" before I redirected "old.com" to "new.com)"

The problem now is, I add "addon2.com" (another addon domain), but I can't access this domain... When I try to access this "addon2.com", it will redirect me to old.com/hxxp://addon.com and shows that the page can't be found....

Can somone help me how to solve this problem? If I remove the redirect code from .htacess, my addon2.com works just fine...

Thanks
Andi

## edited

i added this on my .htaccess

> RewriteEngine on
>
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www.)?addon2.com
>
> RewriteRule (.*) hxxp://new.com/$1 [R=301,L]

and it seems like it works :)

Comment: Do you use cpanel? If yes, you can try from Redirect menu under Domains

Comment: Open up your FTP client (or file manager in your dashboard) and have a quick look at the .htaccess in your /addon2 folder?

Comment: hi, thx for reply...

@dragon sandu yes i'm using cpanel, but it only works for old.com, when i access old.com/page1 , it doesn't redirect to new.com/page1 ...when i try using "wildcard redirect, it shows an error : Redirecting "" to "new.com" will cause a redirection loop because "old.com", which is located at "/home/primalb/public_html/", is above "new.com", which is located at "/home/primalb/public_html/" .